# Worklight 6.1- What does this logs `wl_antiXSRFRealm challenge handler's waiting list` mean when making a call to adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

What does this logs meant which is given below when making a call to adapter. This logs we are getting on Xcode console while testing on `IOS5`,`IOS6`,`IOS7`. I noticed that Whenever we make a call to adapter and if it get success this logs never comes in console.

And if we are not getting any failure and success from adapter after making call to adapter, this `wl_antiXSRFRealm challenge handler's waiting list` logs comes on Xcode console and it stuck over there. Now this time we are not even getting failure and success for adapter call and same logs will remain on Xcode console till we make a another call to adapter.

```
2014-01-23 16:06:13.953 MyApp[78767:a0b] WLRequestBuilder.initWithRootUrl else_url: https://IPADDRESS:443/MyApp/apps/services/api/MyApp/ipad/0/query
2014-01-23 15:40:45.018 MyApp[78116:a0b] Adding request to wl_antiXSRFRealm challenge handler's waiting list
2014-01-23 15:40:45.018 MyApp[78116:a0b] Adding request to wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm challenge handler's waiting list
```

Please let me know , what does that logs means in worklight.

Answer (score 0):

Checked with one of our developers, who said the message is indicating the request requires antiXSRF authentication, but there is already another request that require antiXSRF authentication being processed therefore the second request is added to waiting list.

This should happen only if the developer fires multiple request simultaneosly, however it shouldn't be an issue and SDK should work. According to what you are reporting above, it sounds like the SDK stops firing success/failure events. If so, we can work with you offline on the recreate steps.